# Trying to get Tomcat running with XAMPP

Tags: tomcat, xampp

I have installed XAMPP v3.2.2 and have Apache and MySQL running correctly.  Tomcat will not start though and comes up with the error:

```
Tomcat Started/Stopped with errors, return code: 1
14:37:47  [Tomcat]  Make sure you have Java JDK or JRE installed and the required ports are free
14:37:47  [Tomcat]  Check the "/xampp/tomcat/logs" folder for more information
```

When I open the log, called `catalina.pid` it simply has the PID 8556 (although this value differs each time I try to run Tomcat).

I have changed the default ports for Tomcat.  I have installed both Java JDK (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_65`) and Java JRE (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6`) and set the Environment Variables in Windows System Properties to `JAVA_HOME` and `JRE_HOME` to the previously mentioned file paths.  I'm not sure what else I can try to get past this error?

** Extra info about JRE **

For some reason I have two JRE instances, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6` and `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65`.  Although I have tried setting both in the Environment Variable settings and neither works, I wondered if this may be the cause of the problem?

Comment: Do you have anything else running on port 8080?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to check which ports are in use so I just changed the Tomcat HTTP port to 8081

Comment: No, error message is same regardless

Comment: netstat -na | find "8080" and also make sure you installed jdk/jre

Comment: @Ghayel Yes, I've installed both JDK & JRE

Comment: have you checked what is running on port 8080 or 8081?

Comment: @Ghayel No, nothing for ports 8080 or 8081 - they're not in use

Comment: have you checked /xampp/tomcat/logs?

Comment: Yes, see in the OP the log is `catalina.pid` and simply displays a PID

Comment: Have you set Tomcat paths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems problem with setting paths. Make sure you set the paths example paths:

1. CATALINA_HOME : D:\Java\Tomcat
2. CLASSPATH : D:\Java\Tomcat\lib\servlet-api.jar;D:\Java\Tomcat\lib\jsp-api.jar
3. JAVA_HOME : D:\Java\jdk
4. path : D:\Java\jdk\bin;D:\Java\Tomcat\bin
5. Also you can run Xamp Tomcat with "Administrator" privilege

If you are using skype then check and make sure skype is not using the ports 8080 or 8081. If this is the case then change skype port and restart skype

Comment: Where do I set these paths?  As Environment Variables in Windows System Settings?

Comment: right click > my computer >properties > Advance system settings > Environment variables > System variables > new > variable name e.g. JAVA_HOME > variable value >D:\Java\jdk

Comment: have done, thanks.  Turns out it was a permissions problem as I was using a computer at work with admin restrictions, but your help was useful too - thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to environment variables, In system variables add,

- CATALINA_HOME : C:\xampp\tomcat
- JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92 (Upto your jdk path in your system)

Now go to the folder `C:\xampp\tomcat` then `shift + right click` and choose open command window here and type `catalina_start` then hit enter.

Now to go the xampp contorl panel and start tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Anne Lingesh,
It works as per your answer.

Go to environment variables, In system variables add,

```
CATALINA_HOME : C:\xampp\tomcat

JAVA_HOME : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92 (Upto your jdk path in your system)
```

Now go to the folder `C:\xampp\tomcat` then shift + right click and choose open command window here and type catalina_start then hit enter.

Now to go the xampp contorl panel and start tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the following registry path exist:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit\14

(14 or other number)

The Tomcat starter depends on this.